# how do I make rails/pg/postgresql look for a different hostname/socket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql, pg

how do I make rails/pg look for psql databases at "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" instead of "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the socket option to your database.yml file.

**example:**

```
development:
  host: /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
  adapter: postgresql
  username: root
  password: password
  database: my_app_development
```

Comment: i updated database.yml but rake doesn't seem to use the new option.

Comment: seems like its a bit different for pg, i updated, try using that.